# I am writing a basic python program to check if a string appears in list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I check if a string exists in a list in python?

```
with open('pwds.csv', newline='\n') as csvfile:
global passwordlist
passwords = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
passwordlist = []
for row in passwords:
    global passwordlist
    passwordlist = list(passwords)
    map(lambda passwordlist: str.replace ("['", ""), passwordlist)
    print (passwordlist)
```

I am trying to store data in a CSV file and then read it in python to see if it contains a string given in a user input. At the moment invariably the program cannot find an inputted string in the list even if I have the program print the list to ensure that the string is indeed there. I am simply lost. 
It is a GCSE Computing  challenge task for extension work.

Comment: please fix indentation. There is also several problems with your code. Your iterating on `passwords` but never using `row`.

Comment: 1/ Using `global` only makes sense inside a function. If your code actually is part of a function, the second `global passwordlist` is useless. 2/ You probably meant something like `map(lambda s: s.replace(...), passwordlist)`

Comment: Can you please show the code where you are *actually* trying to check if said string is in the list? The code shown does nothing but repeatedly read the same open csv file to a list (which only produces empty lists after the first time). The ``map`` is never consumed, so it has no effect either.

Comment: What does `pwds.csv` look like? Also, in a real-world situation, you'd never store passwords as plain text but for a challenge, I guess it is okay.

Comment: Do you have any control over how the data is stored? For example, can you instead use dictionary to check if username & password match? What exactly are you storing in this file? JUST the passwords?

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
if a in mylist:
    #do something if "a" is in the list
```

If the list is really big:

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "c"]
myset = set(mylist)
if a in mylist:
    #do something if "a" is in the list
```

Comment: this won't help if the list isn't being formed properly